# redirecting console output of a compiled file to GUI

Tags: java, compilation

I am making an application where I take as input a java program, compile it and show the output after running it on the screen in a text box. I am not able to figure out a way to redirect the output of that program onto the screen.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please show some effort before you ask a question here. Search the internet, try to code something and if you get really stuck, open a question.

Comment: It will depend on how you are running it

Comment: It is completed. I used the method where the person framing the question will put a predefined class where the output of the code will be tested and the result will be stored in a file which then, can later be fetched to print the output of the result on the screen and in any text box. Since, the application was intended for a very small scale this works fine and also the records were required on how much each test taker scored, in a file that is generated by the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process proc = processBuilder.start();
ctrl.clear();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
while(true)
{
    int exitValue;
    try
    {
        proc.exitValue();
        System.out.println("process ended with exit value "+ exitValue);
    }
    catch(IllegalThreadStateException e)
    {// Process is alive
        try
        {
            final String str = reader.readLine();
            if (str!=null)
            {
                //Print the string somewhere
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ignored)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Do note that you have to get the processes instance. How you do that doesn't matter.